# How can I set the TextField size to the same size as a TextField String?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to set TextField width to the same size as the TextField String. 
This is what I make code.

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle 
string += digit!
textField.insertText(string)

textField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: Int(30+textField.font!.pointSize)*textField.text!.count, height: 38)
```

But this work like this image:

[image: [enter image description here]

What will I do?

Comment: can you post your textfield did endEditing? im guessing you are updating this in that delegate?

Comment: I will make textField array. So if I touch 「Button」, it make new textField. And textField update from String type. I update code block.

Comment: why make a new textfield? why not just delete the context of the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think pointSize return to what you are looking for. Try this instead.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textFieldv: UITextField) {
        let digit = "3"
        var string = textFieldv.text!
        string += digit
        textField.text = string

        textField.frame = CGRect(x: textField.frame.origin.x, y: textField.frame.origin.y, width: getWidth(text: string, tf: textField), height: textField.frame.height)
    }

    func getWidth(text: String, tf : UITextField) -> CGFloat
    {
        tf.text = text
        tf.sizeToFit()
        return tf.frame.size.width
    }
}
```

I create a UITextField  in Storyboard . This code works for me